# Get last executed query id in SINGLESTORE

Tags: sql, singlestore

Is there any way to get the last query id executed in Singlestore?

I need a query that returns the identifier of the last query that was executed.

Comment: https://support.singlestore.com/hc/en-us/articles/4406419364244-Queries-logging

Comment: "Last query id?" Please [edit] your question to explain further. Do you need [LAST_INSERT_ID()](https://docs.singlestore.com/managed-service/en/reference/sql-reference/information-functions/last_insert_id.html) ?

Comment: No, I need an identifier of the last query executed, but without altering the database configuration, as I do not have admin permissions.

Comment: Queries do not have identifiers, at least not in mysql, so I guess your question is not applicable to mysql.

Answer (score 0):

In SingleStore you can query the MV_PROCESSLIST in the information_schema database (SELECT * FROM information_schema.mv_processlist) or you can use the SQL query SHOW PROCESSLIST.

You will be able to see queries ID.